# Where can I find data on sales of celery varieties in Europe?

Tags: data-request, europe, food

In the [Wikipedia entry on Celery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Celery), the [Celeriac](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Celeriac) wasn't even mentioned, while it is the "de facto celery" of the Europe. If you walk up to a vegetable stand and ask for celery, you're getting a celery root. If the recipe says "add celery" it means "celery root". Celery stalks are less common, only start gaining popularity and generally, while in the US "celery" as a food product means "celery stalks", in Europe it's "celery root".

I added the following paragraph:

> In Europe the dominant variety of celery most commonly available in trade is Celeriac (Apium graveolens var. rapaceum) grown for its hypocotyl forming a large bulb (commonly but incorrectly called celery root). The leaves are used as seasoning, and the stalks find only marginal use.

And shortly that entry got a "[citation needed]" mark.

Now how do I provide a citation on something that is just too mundane to create any research?
I guess if I linked some statistics that show sales or production of root celery (celeriac) surpassing sales/production of stalk celery (Pascal) it would be satisfactory, but where can I find these?

Answer (score 5):

Eurostat is a European institution which collects data from its member country's statistical institutions and gathers data itself, amongst others stats on the production of vegetables. Here are the [stats for celery and celeriac production across all EU countries](http://appsso.eurostat.ec.europa.eu/nui/show.do?query=BOOKMARK_DS-075769_QID_-FC91D32_UID_-3F171EB0&layout=CROP_PRO,L,X,0;TIME,C,X,1;GEO,L,Y,0;STRUCPRO,L,Z,0;INDICATORS,C,Z,1;&zSelection=DS-075769STRUCPRO,PR;DS-075769INDICATORS,OBS_FLAG;&rankName1=STRUCPRO_1_2_-1_2&rankName2=INDICATORS_1_2_-1_2&rankName3=CROP-PRO_1_2_0_0&rankName4=TIME_1_0_1_0&rankName5=GEO_1_2_0_1&pprRK=FIRST&pprSO=PROTOCOL&ppcRK=FIRST&ppcSO=PROTOCOL&rStp=&cStp=&rDCh=&cDCh=&rDM=true&cDM=true&footnes=false&empty=false&wai=false&time_mode=ROLLING&lang=EN&cfo=###,###.###). A summation across all countries for the years 2000-2011 shows the following production in 1000 tonnes:

- celery: 3194.9
- celeriac: 3817.2

It is interesting to see though that the production data provided by Eurostat on The Netherlands differs in some cells from the [Statitistics Netherlands (CBS) data](http://statline.cbs.nl/StatWeb/publication/?VW=T&DM=SLEN&PA=37738ENG&D1=a&D2=14,21&D3=a&HD=130523-1354&LA=EN&HDR=T,G2&STB=G1).

Comment: That's nice but it doesn't contain exports and imports, so it's not reflecting sales, I'm afraid. Especially when contrasting easily perishable greens (celery ribs) vs vegetables of months of shelf life (celery root) the proportions between domestic production vs imports from far countries may be strongly biased

Comment: True, I'll have a look for sales stats, but I guess might want to edit your question which still states *some statistics that show sales or production* :)

Comment: I can't find sales or balance statistics purely for celery and celeriac :(

Comment: I don't expect to see ones "purely for" of course, just a table containing a row with it. Besides, "production + import - export = sales" (although that may include sales as animal feeder and such, but I don't think celery or celeriac is common in that application.)

Comment: @SF. with 'purely for' I meant, stats at the level of celery/celeriac. Instead there are only sales/import/export/balance data on the aggregate level of vegetables and none 'purely for' celery/celeriac, as far as I can find :(